# Ensure that Impala query gets materialized

Tags: cloudera-cdh, impala, bigdata

It there any reliable and efficient way to ensure that impala query results gets fully materialized without printing results to console?
As example I will use INNER JOIN query.

The obvious way to materialize query results is to *create table as select*.

```
CREATE TABLE t3 STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT t1.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

The problem with it is that it writes to disc therefore is inefficient. I'm looking for most efficient way to execute query and ensure results are materialized.

As an example, in Spark I can use `.cache` method followed by `.count` to ensure query is materialized.

```
val t3 = t1.join(t2, "id")
t3.cache
t3.count
```

I could try workaround with sub-query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT t1.* FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id) t3;
```

But still I need to ensure the sub-query is materialized, which is not obvious if query optimizer discovers that I'm only interested in total count. Maybe there are some hints to enforce that or other tricks?

Comment: You want a query to be materialized, but you don't want the query to be materialized (i.e. data persisted to disk). I see a kind of contradiction there. Or maybe you just want to stress-test the Impala daemons, just to see at which point they give up with OOM?

Comment: In other words: Impala is a SQL execution engine, not a data processing framework (*à la* Spark), not a distributed cache (*à la* Redis). When a query had been executed, nothing remains. Except a few logs.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thanks for comment, in many sql db you can save query results into variable on ad-hoc basis and re-use it further. If impala would have such feature it would solve my case. I want to materialize query, but I don't want to have result transmit/print overhead, so the `select count(*)` outer query - much better than *create table as select*. I don't think there is contradiction. Just a precise timing of query execution on server side.

Comment: Ah, now I understand -- you just want to store a *scalar* value into a *variable*. That's not a **SQL** feature; you would need a proprietary **procedural language wrapper** extension such as PL/SQL, PgSQL, T-SQL, or whatever name MySQL gives to the half-baked stuff they offer for stored procedures.

Comment: There are various extensions in various dbs. All I want is to precisely measure query execution time on the database side. SELECT COUNT(*) isn't reliable as it can get optimized by query optimizer and query eventually may not get materialized. Maybe there is another ways to avoid fetching results overhead? redirecting query results into `/dev/null` or something else?

Comment: *"All I want is to precisely measure query execution time"* -- **why didn't you tell that in the first place?**

Comment: Parquet is a columnar format, so some optimizations could be done if you were asking for single-col aggregations, but not so if you kind of merge all columns on each row. So there is no way the Impala optimizer could avoid a brute-force, row-by-row table scan when requested to compute `SELECT zorglub, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT LENGTH(CONCAT(a,b,CAST(c AS STRING),......) AS zorglub FROM t1) wtf GROUP BY zorglub`

Comment: *Side note - the example query above is "embarrassingly parallel" until you get to the final sum-of-partial-counts, so it should be representative of the Impala throughput in real life. Notwithstanding the random effects of HDFS file blocks location vs. Impala daemons location, concurrency, etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that with **Impala**, and will never be able to.
Cloudera designed that tool specifically to support BI tools such as Tableau, Qlik, MicroStrategy etc. -- but not to support *ad hoc* ETL scripts.

On the other hand **Hive** now ships with a "HPL-SQL" procedural language wrapper that might fit your needs. Caveats:

- requires Hive 2.0+
- requires running your whole script *inside* the HPL-SQL interpreter, not the base Hive client (nor a standard JDBC connection)

And that **HPL-SQL tool** claims that it also **supports Impala queries** but I never investigated that claim. Could solve your problem, as a kind of clumsy workaround.

References:
  [HIVE-11055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11055) (PL/HQL tool contributed to the Hive code base)
  [HPL/SQL website](http://www.hplsql.org/)

---

Speaking of workarounds, why not use **Spark**, as you suggested yourself? You might read the Impala/Hive tables, either with Spark native Parquet libraries, or with a custom JDBC connection to an Impala daemon. In essence it would be similar to a HPL/SQL solution.

Comment: Thanks. Well answered. I will wait with bounty a while. I'm already using Spark in the benchmark, wanted to reflect Impala more precisely. Looks like the best way is to tests two different queries `select count(*)` and `create table as select` so reader can use desired measure for his/her use case.